# how to use reload data in table view while working with two view?

Tags: iphone

I have two classes. In my first class i have table view which contains list of countries. And in my second view i have a picker which contain sorting by name. And i have button in my first class. On this button click i go on second class. In second class when i click on picker like sorting by name then the picker value store into `NSMutableString`. So i want that when i go back to my first view i want to show list according to the second class picker value. I use table reload in the `viewWillAppear` method of first view but its not working. Sometimes it crashes.

```
 -(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
    {

        if(secondClassObj.isActStrPicker>=0)
        {

            sortByResultStr=[[NSString alloc]init];
            sortByResultStr=[secondClassObj  pickerValueStr];
            NSLog(@"picker class value of sorting  string fetech %@ if part sssssss",sortByResultStr);
        }
        else
        {
            //the else part is not working
            NSLog(@"picker class value fetech %@ else part sssssss",[cmpnyPickCheckObj isActStrPicker]);

        }
        [countrytableView reloadData];
    }
```

And i want that table shows value according to isActStrPicker(string) when i come back on this first view.
Thanks for helping me

Comment: Your basic idea of calling `-reloadData` in `-viewWillAppear:` is fine.  What happens when it crashes? The likely answer is that you've made an error in memory management and an object has been deallocated, but without details it's impossible to say for sure.

Comment: @Seamus Campbell..Now my application is not crashing.I remove this problem but my data in table view not reloading...I don't know why plz help..

Comment: Check that `countrytableview` is actually connected to your table view and is not nil.

Comment: my table view name is countrytableview.and it is not nil...but it is not reloaded.I don't know why...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try Call **NSNotificationCenter**

You can reload the tableView when you are not in that VIEW;

**1. First
In FirstVC.m, register a NSNotificationCenter, like this**

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
                                         selector:@selector(reloadtableview) 
                                             name:@"ReloadTableView"
                                           object:nil];
```

-(void)reloadtableview
{

//reload tableview

}

2*.Call this method to ask them to reload tableview:*

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"ReloadTableView" object:nil];
```

Comment: you have to put the reload tableview data in <<reloadtableview>> function

Comment: i put reload tableview in <<reloadtableview>>funtion but not reloading my table view data

Comment: Make sure the tableview is connected with the tableview in .xib if you are using a .xib file.